# Standard Young Tableau Help

Tags: abstract-algebra

Use the hook-length formula to calculate the number of SYT of shape (3,2,1). [3 blocks on top row, 2 blocks on second row, 1 block on third and final row]

Write down all the SYT of this same shape.

Write out the path corresponding to each SYT from the previous question.

I'm expected to learn this, but this isn't in my textbook and I can't find anything online that is very easily comprehensible. Any help?!

Comment: For the first problem, the number of standard Young tableaux is the dimension of the corresponding irreducible representation. This can be calculated using the formula given on wiki : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau